# Starting the instance of mongodb-memory-server failed on Unit Testing with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a micro service running with **Express** and save data to **MongoDB** using **mongoose 6.x.x** version. I am trying to test it with **supertest** and **jest**.

I'm setting up some hooks to create an instance of **Mongo Memory Server** on version **8.x.x**, using the beforeAll hooks as showed in the example:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 
let mongod: any;
 
beforeAll(async () => {
  mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const uri = mongod.getUri();
  await mongoose.connect(uri);
});
```

*The mongod variable tries to reach a global scope.*

At this point I get the error:

> Starting the instance failed, enable debug for more information.

Therefore, I cannot use the instance in tests. I have enabled debug mode. And I get this errors about the mongo instance:

> MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[52463]: start: Starting Processes +8ms
> MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[52463]: _launchMongod: Launching Mongod
> Process +1ms   MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[52463]: prepareCommandArgs
> +0ms   MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[52463]: prepareCommandArgs: final argument
> array:["--port","52463","--dbpath","/var/folders/wt/d0s3lj915wd5pyvc9r7zdfx40000gn/T/mongo-mem--10268-fsntc7R8OJql","--storageEngine","ephemeralForTest","--bind_ip","127.0.0.1","--noauth"] +0ms
> MongoMS:MongoMemoryServer Mongo[unknown]: stop: Called .stop() method +23ms
> MongoMS:MongoMemoryServer Mongo[unknown]: stop: "instanceInfo" is not defined (never ran?) +0ms

The error is genereted because instance is not defined and I am trying to call mongod.stop in afterAll hooks to stop the instance.

Anyone has an idea of this?

Comment: Are you running your app in a docker container?

Comment: Getting this error on Fedora 36 as well

Comment: @TusharMistry is a version error. Look the answer I did myself down.

Comment: Had a problem it seems mongodb binaries problem [Issue](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues/673)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was caused by an incompatibility in the architecture of my Mac. Normally the software would load, but it would not start the instance because the correct software was not running.

On Mac devices with ARM architecture, the use of Rosetta 2 is essential. As of version 7.x.x of MongoDB Memory Server the package downloads the software with correct architecture, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by adding a `.dockerignore`-file

```
# ignore all node_modules, no matter where, like when having a monorepo
**/node_modules
```